How to align elements in R Shiny action button?
This is one of those pesky little formatting issues. I'm creating an action button in R Shiny and I am trying to better align the information icon with the text string rendered by the action button. Basically I want the information icon and text string rendered in 2 closely adjacent columns as illustrated in the second image below. MWE code is at the bottom of this post. How can this be done?

Code:
library(shiny)

button_tmp <- function(x, y) {
  actionButton(
    x, y,
    icon = icon("info-circle"),
    style = "text-align:left;
             white-space: normal;
             word-wrap: break-word;"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      button_tmp("test_button", "This is a long text that needs to wrap around and align with icon.")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Main Panel")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)


I have never worked with R, but here is my try. There is a css propertie for the marker postition in a list. list-style-position you can  set it to inside or outside.
But i don't know if this works for this.

Couldn't get this to work but fiddling with this led me to a working solution shown below

Below is a solution, using a "Flexbox" layout:
library(shiny)

button_tmp <- function(x, y) {
  actionButton(
    x,
    label = div(
      style = "display: inline-flex; align-items: top;",
      div(style = "padding-right: 5px;", icon("info-circle")),  # Icon to the left
      span(style = "white-space: normal;", y)  # Text to the right
    ),
    style = "background-color:transparent;
             border:none;
             padding:0;
             text-align:left;
             white-space: normal;
             word-wrap: break-word;"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      button_tmp("test_button", "This is a long text that needs to wrap around and align with the icon.")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Main Panel")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)

